# jquery function not defined - scope issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have a likely simple problem that I need help with.

I have two js files that I have loaded on a page via  tag in html.  All the code in both these files is executed / loaded within `$(document).ready();`

On a certain event, function A defined in the first file tries to call function B defined in the other file.  However, this fails, I get an error that function B is not defined.

I notice that if I take the definition of function B outside of `$(document).ready()`, that function A is able to call function B - it is in scope.

Why?

Comment: yep, scope issue. JavaScript has function scope, so the functions you've created inside the document.ready callback are accessible inside that function only ***unless*** you make the function `A` global by attaching it to the global object (`window` for browsers). But that won't be the right solution - I'm sure there's a better solution than that.

Comment: haha... of course.  it seems obvious now.  the second file has functions that I have made agnostic so they can be global.  I was under the impression that code that runs within the ready callback would be global.  thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a scope issue.  Everything defined within a function is accessible only within that function unless made global in some other way.  When you move the function outside of the ready function it becomes global making it accessible globally.

EDIT: When I say "made global in some other way", I mean something like this:

```
window.something = "something";
```

This will create a global variable `something` even if this line of code exists within your ready function.

Comment: Thanks James. new to JQuery, and thought that anything in .ready would still magically have a global scope.

Comment: so it means function inside document.ready don't have global scope, but we can assign global scope to a variable by using the window method.